# Displaying cached image via Cache API

Tags: javascript, browser-cache, cacheapi

I'm trying to use the Cache API to store large files (one being 500MB) for offline use. I'm able to create/open the cache, fetch the image URL from AWS S3, and put it into the cache:

```
let cache = await caches.open('my-cache');

let url = 'https://[mybucket].s3.amazonaws.com/example.png';

await fetch(url).then( async (response) => {
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new TypeError("Bad response status");
  }

  return cache.put(url, response);
});
```

This appears properly in the inspector with (what I think) are the correct CORS/content size responses:

[image: Cache storage]

I'm also able to find it in the cache, however instead of searching for the full S3 url it seems to only store it with `/example.png` as the match:

```
const options = {
  ignoreSearch: true,
  ignoreMethod: true,
  ignoreVary: true
};

let img = await cache.match('/example.png', options);
```

This returns a `ReadableStream` successfully, but I don't know where to go next.

I am hoping to default to loading from the cache since the file sizes can get quite large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the documentation for [`Cache.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/match), what you're getting in response should be - well, a [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response)! So, from there, you can use [`Response.blob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/blob) and pass that into [`URL.createObjectURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL), which you can make the `src` of your image.

That was a mouthful, so here it is in code.

```js
// Get the cached item...
const options = {
  ignoreSearch: true,
  ignoreMethod: true,
  ignoreVary: true
};

let img = await cache.match('/example.png', options);

// Handle the possibility of undefined
if(img === undefined) { return false; }

// Convert the image data to a blob...
let blob = img.blob();

// Assuming imgElement is our image element...
imgElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

// And finish it all off nicely.
return true;
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to blob img.body instead of img itself.